# does distinct work with GAE Python SDK - 1.9.4 release

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Code:

```
pages = Line.gql("where projectNAME='%s'"%(projectName)).run(projection=["projectNAME","pageno"],distinct=True)
```

This show the following error,

```
TypeError: Unknown configuration option ('distinct')
```

Why so?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the documentation for `run` may be incorrect. It isn't possible to provide the `distinct` option there. Instead, try specifying what you want inside the GQL string:

```py
pages = db.GqlQuery('SELECT DISTINCT pageno FROM Line WHERE projectNAME=:1', projectName).run()
```

Note that here the only projection specified is `pageno`. It is not possible to specify a projection that is used in an equality (note you know what the projectNAME is already because you specified it).